# MFTF stand alone - Could not retrieve API token from Magento Instance (302 Found) error

Tags: magento2.3, mftf

I installed MFTF stand alone and have a magento instance. Just following the getting started document before I write tests of my own. When generated/run the test it gives error -  Could not retrieve API token from Magento Instance (302 Found).

Any help is really appreciated

In ModuleResolver.php line 444:

Could not retrieve API token from Magento Instance (302 Found)

generate:tests [-c|--config CONFIG] [-f|--force] [-i|--time TIME] [-t|--tests TESTS] [-d|--debug] [-r|--remove] [--] [...]

Answer (score 3):

probably you have wrong credentials to Magento instance.

Look in ModuleResolver where API token is retrieving from Magento:

```
    /**
     * Get the API token for admin.
     *
     * @return string|boolean
     */
    protected function getAdminToken()
    {
        $login = $_ENV['MAGENTO_ADMIN_USERNAME'] ?? null;
        $password = $_ENV['MAGENTO_ADMIN_PASSWORD'] ?? null;
        if (!$login || !$password || !$this->getBackendUrl()) {
            $message = "Cannot retrieve API token without credentials and base url, please fill out .env.";
            $context = [
                "MAGENTO_BASE_URL" => getenv("MAGENTO_BASE_URL"),
                "MAGENTO_BACKEND_BASE_URL" => getenv("MAGENTO_BACKEND_BASE_URL"),
                "MAGENTO_ADMIN_USERNAME" => getenv("MAGENTO_ADMIN_USERNAME"),
                "MAGENTO_ADMIN_PASSWORD" => getenv("MAGENTO_ADMIN_PASSWORD"),
            ];
            throw new TestFrameworkException($message, $context);
        }

        $url = ConfigSanitizerUtil::sanitizeUrl($this->getBackendUrl()) . $this->adminTokenUrl;
        $data = [
            'username' => $login,
            'password' => $password
        ];
        $headers = [
            'Content-Type: application/json',
        ];

        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        $responseCode = curl_getinfo($ch)['http_code'];

        if ($responseCode !== 200) {
            if ($responseCode == 0) {
                $details = "Could not find Magento Backend Instance at MAGENTO_BACKEND_BASE_URL or MAGENTO_BASE_URL";
            } else {
                $details = $responseCode . " " . Response::$statusTexts[$responseCode];
            }

            $message = "Could not retrieve API token from Magento Instance ({$details})";
            $context = [
                "tokenUrl" => $url,
                "responseCode" => $responseCode,
                "MAGENTO_ADMIN_USERNAME" => getenv("MAGENTO_ADMIN_USERNAME"),
                "MAGENTO_ADMIN_PASSWORD" => getenv("MAGENTO_ADMIN_PASSWORD"),
            ];
            throw new TestFrameworkException($message, $context);
        }

        return json_decode($response);
    }
```

**My advice is to check `.env` file in `ROOT/dev/test/acceptance/.env`**

Comment: In .env file, default admin name or admin registration name?

Comment: MAGENTO_BASE_URL= URL for frontend

MAGENTO_BACKEND_NAME= URL name for backend(default after magento installation is admin_xxxxxxx. You can check in 
MAGE_ROOT/app/etc/env.php)

MAGENTO_ADMIN_USERNAME= admin login

MAGENTO_ADMIN_PASSWORD= admin password

Comment: in my case there is no .env file what should I do now?

Answer (score 2):

If you got this problem 
You should change info of file dot-env related with your instance such as 
`MAGENTO_BASE_URL` `MAGENTO_ADMIN_USERNAME` `MAGENTO_ADMIN_PASSWORD`
Make sure set write permissions recurssive to folder

> magento_root\dev\tests

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same message when I forgot to make

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

after I added some modules and tried to generate MFTF tests.